# Adjusting desktop notification behavior in Lubuntu 20.04LTS

Tags: lubuntu, notification

I just installed Lubuntu 20.04LTS and am overall super liking it.  One annoying feature is that if a window or application has an alert it will cause whatever virtual desktop I'm working in to be dropped and switch immediately to that desktop -- which is annoying at best, but could be quite catastrophic if I'm sharing my screen on a Zoom call and suddenly it switches to a private email message that others shouldn't see.  It is mainly doing this with Thunderbird, when an email fails to send.  But if that behavior is system-wide, I'd like to choose a different way of being alerted.

How can I have it just wait until I happen to go to that desktop and see the alert?  (As every other version of Linux I've ever tried has done?)

Comment: "Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once." from [here](https://askubuntu.com/help/closed-questions) in the section titled *Needs more focus*.

Comment: If you go into *Configure Panel* then *Task Manager Settings*, you'll find a checkbox that lets you select if windows are shown for *Current* or defined desktops. Thus you'll can limit *Task Manager* to show only active window's tasks (my preference).  I've not noticed any notifications switch my desktop (though I've specific applications do it) so I suspect that issue is the application... Which application are you talking about (I've noted `tor-browser` switch desktops at times, but it's the only example I can think of currently)

Comment: You do appreciate that you get to accept just **one** answer. So if someone posts an "accept-worthy" answer to *one* of your questions and someone else posts an "accept-worthy" answer to the other question, which one will you accept?

Comment: @guiverc I've split this question.  Your comment answered it, so please check this question:  I'll mark your response correct.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243017/how-can-the-toolbar-show-only-the-windows-active-on-my-current-virtual-desktop

Comment: Apologies for not focusing the question properly...I've since split it into two.  Thank you!