# How can the toolbar show only the windows active on my current virtual desktop?

Tags: lubuntu

I have just installed Lubuntu 20.04LTS and am trying to solve some issues.  It's a minor annoyance, but the desktop pager (and toolbar) doesn't show only the applications that are currently in the desktop I'm in.  For instance, if I'm in Virtual Desktop 7, I'd like to only see the Firefox window that's up there, not the Firefox window that's in 8 or 3.  I'd like to only see the terminal that's concurrent to this virtual desktop.  Instead, I hover over my qterminal bar in the toolbar and 7 or 8 options pop up, and it may be the 6th one down that's the one in my current desktop.  Is there any way to adjust either of these things?

Thank you!

Comment: Is "qterminal bar" correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/5/5.1/lxqt-panel.html for details on using the panel.

From the *Configure Panel* option (prior link) you can select the *Task Manager* and then Settings.

The first option is to "*Show only windows from desktop*" - Make that say Current to see only windows for your current desktop in the Task Manager on the Panel.

[image]